# An inequality $|x^{1/n}-y^{1/n}|\leq c|x-y|^{1/n}$

Tags: inequality

> I need to prove that $|x^{1/n}-y^{1/n}|\leq c|x-y|^{1/n}$, where $x,y\in [0,+\infty)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$, and $c=2^{(n-1)/n}$.

I tried a lot ways for proving cases $n=2$ and $n=3$, but are quite different, I don't know how to prove the general case.

I've done case $n=2$ in the following way. I was prove that $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\leq \sqrt{|x-y|}$ squaring both sides when $x\geq y$.

The case $n=3$ I've done in a similar way. I was prove that $|\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{y}|\leq \sqrt[3]{|x-y|}$ cubing both sides, but is quite different for the case $n=2$. I don't know if it is possible prove using induction with a binomial expansion. I only prove both cases $n=1$, $n=2$ using $c=1\leq 2^{(n-1)/n}$, therefore I proved a better inequality for the first two cases.

Comment: Check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143173/showing-the-inequality-alpha-betap-leq-2p-1-alphap-betap, then try some change of variable to the inequality in above thread to get the inequality you want.

Comment: Is so similar inequalitty. Thanks I'll try it by this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $a,b\geq 0$. Then expanding $(a+b)^n$ with the binomial formula gives 
$$a^n+b^n\leq (a+b)^n.\tag1$$

Without loss of generality, assume that $x\geq y$.
Substitute $a=x^{1/n}-y^{1/n}$ and $b=y^{1/n}$ into  (1) and take the $1/n$ th power 
 to get  your inequality with $c=1$.

Comment: Really easy your answer. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Glad to be of help.